# Marking an item as newly added in TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UITableView where I can add a new item with a touch of a button. I would like to highlight this newly added item. Since UITableView is data-driven and cells are recycled, the only way I can think of so far to mark this newly added item is to add a `BOOL` flag in the data itself, then highlight the cell and negate the flag on first encounter.

Is there another way of doing this without having to contaminate the data source?

Comment: Perhaps you could set up a separate reusable cell to be return to the tableview in cellForRowAtIndexPath - this 'alternate' cell could have some additional visual style applied to it and would only be returned if it were requested via your add button's action method. If the user adds yet another cell, the previously 'highlighted new' cell could be swapped out for a normal cell, and the process can repeat? Im only thinking of this conceptually, so I'm sure it's a bit more tricky than described.

Comment: @DarekRossman That sounds a little more involved that I would like. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thoughts..

1. Create an Integer `[myObjectArray count];`
2. When you add the new object you can reload table
3. Create a new integer `[myObjectArray count];`
4. Compare the two integers when table reloads. If the 1st `int` is less than the new `int`
   then you obviously have added another object.
5. When creating cell check if the  cell indexpath.row is equal to the last object count in your array, if it is then you can fill the cell background with another color.

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks, I ended up implementing a variant of this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is ordered and indexable, use another `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`) of `NSIndexPath` to maintain a list of newly added data. If you only have one section, then you could substitute `NSNumber` for `NSIndexPath` and just record the rows.